# mean function of two floats in python

Tags: python, mean

We want to optimize some coding in Python, and in that case we're looking at our 'lazy' coding. To optimize our program, we want to use classes and functions! (we're new at python), and in that case, we have set up a class called Update:

```
class Update:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last

    def mean(self):
        print (self.first, self.last)
        return ((self.first + self.last) / 2)
```

What we want to do with our program is to generate 3x new average values out of 2 floats.

for example we start with:

```
first[-1] = 33.31
last[-1] = 29.81

average = 31.56
```

then we want to take upper average:

```
(29.81+31.56)/2 = 30.69
```

Lower average:

```
(33.31+31.56)/2 = 32.44
```

At last we want a list showing: {33.31, 32.44, 31.56, 30.69, 29.81}

Unfortunately, our mean function is not working as wished, and when we are running our program we receive following error:

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3257: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  out=out, **kwargs)
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:161: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
```

Alright, so this is what we do. Keep in mind that we're stuck at average of our two values, and then after we will be able to find upper and lower average. Commented lines of code is how the program was initially programmed, and is what we want to optimize.

```
upd = Update(first[-1], last[-1]) # first = 33.31 and last = 29.81

# f = first[-1]
# l = last[-1]

mean_list = []

# mean_list.append(f)
# mean_list.append(l)

first_mean = []
third_mean = []

# mean = np.mean(mean_list)

# first_mean.append(f)
# third_mean.append(l)

first_mean.append(upd.first)
third_mean.append(upd.last)

# first_mean.append(mean)
# third_mean.append(mean)

mean = upd.mean()

first_mean.append(mean)
third_mean.append(mean)

a = np.mean(first_mean).round(2)
b = np.mean(third_mean).round(2)
mean = np.mean(mean_list).round(2)
```

Comment: I notice you never append anything to `mean_list`. Is that intentional? What should `np.mean([])` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem seems to be the empty variable mean_list.
For the general task I suggest you have a look into [numpy's linespace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).

```
import numpy as np
first = 33.31
last = 29.81
means = np.linspace(first, last, 5)
print(means)

> [33.31  32.435 31.56  30.685 29.81 ]
```

You can naturally use this from within your class method.